# HTML5 video with javascript - syntax confusion

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to make a custom video.  I can get my functions to work.  However when I have two event listeners together:

e.g. video.ontimeupdate

only the bottom one will operate when I play the video.  Is there a better way for me to write my functions, so that I do not have this problem?

Event listeners

```
time.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime, true);
video.ontimeupdate = function() {currentTime()};

seek.addEventListener("timeupdate", progressBarUpdate, true);
video.ontimeupdate = function() {progressBarUpdate()};
```

Function code example

// Updating the progress bar function

```
function progressBarUpdate() {

            // Calculate the progress bar value
            var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
            // Update the progress bar value
            seek.value = value;
        }
```

Comment: use `video.addEventListener('timeupdate', ...)` just like you do with `time.addEventListener` and `seek.addEventListener` - I'm not sure what `time` and `seek` objects are, but the code looks wrong to begin with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different JavaScript mechanisms for registering event handlers:

```
time.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime, true);  // W3C DOM Standard
video.ontimeupdate = function() { currentTime() };         // Event handling property
```

When you use a property (`ontimeupdate`) and you give it a value, that value will be overwritten when you set that property to another value.

So, when you do this:

```
video.ontimeupdate = function() {currentTime()};
```

It gets overridden by this later:

```
video.ontimeupdate = function() { progressBarUpdate() };
```

To prevent this from happening, use the more modern **[W3C DOM Level 2 event handling model](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)** that uses `addEventListener`

```
 video.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime);
 video.addEventListener("timeupdate", progressBarUpdate);
```

This will register both functions as callbacks to the `timeupdate` event.

Additionally, there is a third parameter for `addEventListener` (a boolean) which indicates whether you want the callback to fire during the capture phase (`true`) or the bubbling phase (`false`). It's rather unusual to need the capture phase (it's not supported in IE until IE 9), so you may want to modify your existing `true` values to `false` or just omit the third argument as `false` is the default.

Here's a working example that actually shows 3 event handlers all tied into the `timeupdate` event (make sure to scroll down in the snippet window to see the messages):

```js
var videoElement = null;
var current = null
var duration = null;
var div1, div2;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Get DOM References to media element:
  videoElement = document.getElementById('bikeSafe');

  // ...to video span elements:
  current = document.getElementById('current');
  duration = document.getElementById('duration');
  div1 = document.getElementById("timeUpdate1");
  div2 = document.getElementById("timeUpdate2");

  // Wire Up Video to use its API:
  videoElement.addEventListener("play", setCounter);
  videoElement.addEventListener("ended", endVideo);
  videoElement.addEventListener("durationchange", updateStatus);
  videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", setCounter);
  videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateDiv1);
  videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateDiv2);
});

// Video API:

function updateDiv1(){ div1.innerHTML = "Hello from timeupdate event handler!" }
function updateDiv2(){ div2.innerHTML = "Hello from different timeupdate event handler!" }

// Set the value for the current position in the video
function setCounter() {
  // This function is wired up to the video element's timeupdate event, which
  // fires when the current time value changes.
  current.innerHTML = (videoElement.duration - videoElement.currentTime).toFixed(3);
}

function endVideo() {
  // Reset video back to beginning when it ends
  videoElement.currentTime = 0;
};

function updateStatus() {
  // This will fire when the video's durationchange event fires
  // and that will happen upon the successful loading of the image
  // for the first time when it becomes known how long the duration
  // of the video is.
  current.innerHTML = videoElement.duration.toFixed(3);
  duration.innerHTML = videoElement.duration.toFixed(3);
};
```

```css
video { width:40%; }
```

```html
<video id="bikeSafe" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
<p>
  Time Remaining: <span id="current"></span> | 
  Total Length: <span id="duration"></span>
</p>
      
<div id="timeUpdate1"></div>
<div id="timeUpdate2"></div>
```

Comment: Third parameter got updated in latest revs, it is now an option object.

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting, but the DOM Living Standard says that and W3C DOM Level 4 says third arg is boolean. WHATWG vs. W3C

Comment: Yes w3c still says it's a boolean, but all browsers except IE start to support it, so even w3C will incorporate it in their version of the specs.

Comment: Yes, but all browsers will continue to support the W3C spec as well, so I see this as a situation where you can pass either. It's no guarantee that W3C will adopt WHATWG.

Comment: Thank you Scott Marcus for taking the time to explain the syntax.  Your time is much appreciated.

Comment: I have taken the 'true' phase from the video.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime); but I do not know how to get the eventListener to function when the video is playing without using :  video.ontimeupdate = function() {currentTime()};   Do you know what step I am missing?

Comment: @T.XL You can hook up multiple event handlers to the same event by adding additional `addEventListener()` calls as I've shown in my answer, but you can also check out this Fiddle I made that does it: https://jsfiddle.net/4p31vegL/4/

Comment: @Scott Marcus.  Thank you very much, I understand what you mean now.  Thank you for your time, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @T.XL No problem. Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

`video.ontimeupdate` is similar to [`window.onload`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510956/2151050). They are properties that are updated. The most recent function definition for them will be executed. Use `addEventListener()`

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime, true);
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", progressBarUpdate, true);
```

Here is a snippet showing the problem with using `window.onload` syntax.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  console.log('Window loaded #1'); // Will not excecute
}
window.onload = function(){
  console.log('Window loaded #2'); // Window loaded #2
}
```